# Not showing username, phone number and institution in the frontend from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MOM Login</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/logo2.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <!-- Import Firebase libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>

  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-auth.js";
  
    const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBiydb9tqJp526GBYwTqv3S7P_ErmOntLg",
            authDomain: "mom-login-a6e00.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://mom-login-a6e00-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "mom-login-a6e00",
            storageBucket: "mom-login-a6e00.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "14987956774",
            appId: "1:14987956774:web:f55080976493fa99a20ce7"
        };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
  
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const email = user.email;
        const usernameSpan = document.getElementById('email');
        usernameSpan.textContent = email;

      } else {
        console.log("No user is currently logged in");
      }
    });
  </script>
  
  
  
</head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href = "index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"><h4>&nbsp&nbsp;Miracles of Math</h4></a>
  
      <div class="navigation">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#">PROBLEMS</a>
                  <ul class ="droppdown">
                    <li><a href="prev_contest.html">PREVIOUS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="more_prob.html">MORE</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li><a href="login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="profile-section">
    <h2>User Info:</h2>
    
      <p>Username: <span id="email"></span></p>
      
    
  </div>
</body>



  


     





</html>
```

This is the profile.html, where I succeeded in displaying email but cannot show username, phone number, and institution. I stored these data by registration. HTML (I use a sign-in authentication with email and password only, and did not use real-time database still now) Here is the registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MOM Registration</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/logo2.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


    <body>
        <nav>
    
            <a href = "index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg"><h4>&nbsp&nbsp;Miracles of Math</h4></a>
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">PROBLEMS</a>
                        <ul class ="droppdown">
                          <li><a href="prev_contest.html">PREVIOUS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="more_prob.html">MORE</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
        <div id="login-box">
            <div class="left">
                <img src = "Images/bg.png">

            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h1 id='status'>Registration</h1>
                
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
                <input type="text" id="institution" name="institution" placeholder="Institution Name" />
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

                <input type="submit" onclick="showPopup()" id='login' name="login" value="Registration" /><br><br>
                <div id="popup-success" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                      <h2>Registration Successful</h2><br>
                      <p>You can now log in with this account</p><br>
                      <button class="close-popup" onclick="hidePopup()">OK</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div id="popup-error" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                      <h2>Login Error</h2><br>
                      <p>Registration failed. Please try again.</p><br>
                      <button class="close-popup" onclick="hidePopup()">OK</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <p>Already have an account? <a class="Regii" onclick="window.location.href = 'login.html';">Login</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getDatabase, set, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-database.js";
        import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-auth.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBiydb9tqJp526GBYwTqv3S7P_ErmOntLg",
            authDomain: "mom-login-a6e00.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://mom-login-a6e00-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "mom-login-a6e00",
            storageBucket: "mom-login-a6e00.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "14987956774",
            appId: "1:14987956774:web:f55080976493fa99a20ce7"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const auth = getAuth();

        login.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var institution = document.getElementById('institution').value;
            var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in 
                    const user = userCredential.user;

                    console.log(user);
    // Save user information in Firebase Database
    const usersRef = ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid);
    set(usersRef, {
                        username: username,
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        institution: institution,
                        phone: phone
                      
                    });

                    var popupSuccess = document.getElementById("popup-success");
  var popupError = document.getElementById("popup-error");
  popupSuccess.style.display = "block";
    popupError.style.display = "none";
    location.href = 'login.html';
                   
    
                    // ...
                })
               
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    var popupSuccess = document.getElementById("popup-success");
  var popupError = document.getElementById("popup-error");
  popupSuccess.style.display = "none";
    popupError.style.display = "block";
                });

            

                


        });


    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`email` is a property of the `user` object in [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile).

The other data you stored like `username`, `email` (once again), `password`, `institution`, and `phone` are stored in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) which has its own methods to get and read data.

You can use a method such as [`onValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) to read data from Firebase Realtime Database.

```js
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js";

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
   if (user) {
      const email = user.email;
      const usernameSpan = document.getElementById("email");
      usernameSpan.textContent = email;
      // define DB as well as define the reference
      const db = getDatabase();
      const userDataRef = ref(db, "users/" + user.uid);
      // using onValue() to get data
      onValue(userDataRef, (snapshot) => {
         const data = snapshot.val(); // all data that are stored inside the user's UID
         console.log(data.username); // username
         console.log(data.password); // password
         console.log(data.institution); // institution
         console.log(data.phone); // phone
      });
   } else {
      console.log("No user is currently logged in");
   }
});
```

Above I check whether the user is signed in or not using `onAuthStateChanged()`, then get `email` as you did through the `user` object then use `onValue` to get the data from Firebase Realtime Database.

There're other methods to read data as well like [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get) or [read data once with an observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_an_observer). Check each method, and find the one that matches your needs.